# how to calculate pagerank of matrix with values between 0-1 in c#?

Tags: c#, matrix, data-mining, pagerank

I have a big matrix with values between 0-1 , and i want to calculate the pagerank of this matrix , what is the best way to do this ? 
Pagerank array save pagerank values of each row in the big matrix

```
PageRank = new double[linesNumber];
        for ( int i=0 ; i<Jdistance.Length ; i++)
        {
            rank = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<Jdistance[i].Length ; j++)
            {
                if(Jdistance[i][j]==0)
                {
                    rank += Jdistance[j][i] / linesNumber;
                    PageRank[i] = 1 - d + d *rank;
                }
                else
                {
                    rank += Jdistance[i][j] / linesNumber;
                    PageRank[i] = 1-d +d*rank;
                }

            }
        }
```

The Jdistance is the matrix with valuse between 0-1. i d'ont sure that i implement the pagerank formula right.